# Activate selecor loaded after site loaded

Tags: jquery, events, onclick

I have a div that is loaded on click event `.send-div`.
I want that when I click on the `.send-div` div the conlsol.log will be activated.

this is my code.

```
  $("#sharf").on("click", ".send-div" ,function() {
       console.log( "dav" );
    });
```

For now I just want to make the console.log inside the function work.

this is the HTML code of the wanted area:

```
    <div id="sharf">
        <div class="send-div">
             <p>text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

- I have jquery loaded.
  I am sure ythis question was asked before. but i couldnt find it
  Thanks

Comment: What are you asking exactly??

Comment: I want the consol log to be activated when I click the `.send-div` div. The issue is that the same div and its content is loaded on click event.

Comment: if the whole `#sharf` div is loaded dynamically, then you cannot attach event handler to it. Use *document*: `$(document).on("click", ".send-div" ...` (or the closest static element).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you mean, since the question seems fairly simple:

```
$(".send-div").click(function() {
   console.log( "clicked send-div" );
});
```